# AOT of framework library

Tags: android

I know that in Kitkat and later versions android does a AOT (Ahead of time compilation), this happen during app install time and result in plenty of performance benefits. But any app would be referencing number of classes from operating system, which I guess they are packaged as jar file somewhere.

Take the example of TextView, so when AOT happens does it also include all the reference to system dependent classes? or AOT it just app exclusive procedure ? in that case a good amount of performance improvements will not be reachable, as we only do a part of processing through our code.

My app is too slow, I am using android system class called **android.text.StaticLayout**, I think if it were also precompiled whether install time or at the time OS itself was installed it would have been faster than what I am facing.

Comment: Speed improvement of AOT is mostly negligeble compared to JIT used in older Androids, the most notable benefit is faster start and smaller memory footprint. If your application is too slow (especially on a modern device running KitKat) then you do something wrong in it and AOT won't help you.

Comment: @StenSoft maybe you are correct as JIT and AOT both do similar thing,  Here I am talking about specific piece of code "android.text.StaticLayout" it takes 4 second when i create an object from it. Also if there is AOT procedure already JIT will be skipped, means system jar files are cursed to run slow.

Comment: System libraries are also compiled with AOT, it won't make much sense to skip them; and the way how ART works, it is not possible to mix AOT and bytecode. If it takes 4 seconds for `StaticLayout` to layout, you do something very wrong with it.

Comment: I am pushing large text in StaticLayout constructor then it is slow, it is happening inside layout/render part of code in staticlayout (which is somewhat similar to any text rendering engine alike webkit), But i am confident that if any text rendering code is written in native C it wont take long time, that is why i am thinking that part of code is running without native compilation or maybe JIT is not good enough. The other reason can be text rendering code of staticlayout is coded with too much complexity.

Comment: If you put a very large text in a browser, it will take very long as well, C cannot do miracles and not even bytecode is *that* slow. You can try putting your text in `WebView` (which is WebKit internally) and see how long it will take to load but my guess would be it will be very similar.

Comment: in the meanwhile i tried few things and found that there isnt much i can do other than somehow limiting the size of text, webview works much better i have seen this, interestingly this staticlayout has its main piece of code (line break detector) implemented inside a private native method.